# This dependency was not found: * core-js/fn/symbol

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, vuex

I am building Vue.js app using Vuex.
when I build, it shows following errors.  I tried to fix installing `npm install --save core-js/fn/symbol`  but no luck.
[image]

here my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.19.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-router": "^3.2.0",
"vuex": "^3.4.0"},
"devDependencies": {
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"node-sass": "^4.12.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"}
```

Actually, I was following just video tutorial, but I don't see any errors in video.
I think this is version issue.
Please advise me. Thank you

---

**Edit:** I have also tried just `npm install --save core-js` but it shows same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Check the 'store/mutations.js' file to make sure that you aren't importing anything extra in your code. When you add the reference to 'species' in the script, VSCode automatically adds an import at the top of the file that looks like this  `import { species } from "core-js/fn/symbol"`.

Remove that and you should be good to go.